# WP Query - duplicated posts once including tags in search results

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, tags

I running WordPress on `IIS & SQL server`. As some of the plugins do not work correctly with **DB ABSTRACTION** I am using a lot of `functions.php` filters as so on.

To make my search results **include tags** I have added the following code to my `functions.php`  - http://pastebin.com/BZG20McY

My search results now **include tags**, but I get plenty of **duplicated posts**.

**Is there any way to filter `WP QUERY` and remove all duplicated post before going into the `WHILE LOOP`?**

Here is my basic loop:

```
<?php

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array('');

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
     $query_split = explode("=", $string);
     $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
} 
$search = new WP_Query($search_query);

?>


<?php if ($search->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($search->have_posts()) : $search->the_post(); ?>
          // SOME POSTS
     <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
// NO POSTS
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Any suggestions much appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

Adding this inside the `WHILE LOOP` will solve the problem. 
It will skip the post in the loop if this post ID is present in our array (meaning, same post went through the loop before).

```
<?php 

    // MAKE SURE YOU DECLARE $postsIDsArray= array(); outside of the loop, on top of it
    $postID = $search->post->ID;

    // if this ID is present in the array, skip this post
    if (in_array($postID, $postsIDsArray)) continue;

    // if the ID is not present, add this ID to the array
    array_push($postsIDsArray, $postID);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First simply check if we got a search query. Do this inside the `pre_get_posts` filter to use conditional tags. If we got a search, attach the filter.

```
function wpse83602_search_query( $query )
{
    if (
        ! $query->is_search()
        OR $query->is_admin
    )
        return $query;

    add_filter( 'posts_distinct', 'wpse83602_posts_distinct' );
    return $query;
}
```

Then just use the `posts_distinct` or the `posts_clauses` filter. Remove the filter im. to not conflict with other queries.

```
function wpse83602_posts_distinct( $clause )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $clause[0] = "DISTINCT";
    return $clause;
}
```